# Initializing Games Client in Android

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm trying the new Google Play Game Services.

At first I followed this howto https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart
and then finished this https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init

I end up like this:

```
05-16 20:01:39.034: E/AndroidRuntime(18257): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-16 20:01:39.034: E/AndroidRuntime(18257): java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information.
05-16 20:01:39.034: E/AndroidRuntime(18257):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.p$f.a(Unknown Source)
05-16 20:01:39.034: E/AndroidRuntime(18257):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.p$f.a(Unknown Source)
05-16 20:01:39.034: E/AndroidRuntime(18257):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.p$b.p(Unknown Source)
05-16 20:01:39.034: E/AndroidRuntime(18257):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.p$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
05-16 20:01:39.034: E/AndroidRuntime(18257):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-16 20:01:39.034: E/AndroidRuntime(18257):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-16 20:01:39.034: E/AndroidRuntime(18257):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-16 20:01:39.034: E/AndroidRuntime(18257):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-16 20:01:39.034: E/AndroidRuntime(18257):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-16 20:01:39.034: E/AndroidRuntime(18257):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-16 20:01:39.034: E/AndroidRuntime(18257):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-16 20:01:39.034: E/AndroidRuntime(18257):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've tried to follow the tutorial step by step. I don't understand what is going wrong.

> ava.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information.

I thought that logcat = logs and there is nothing more. So where can I find these "logs"?

My implementation is different only in one thing. I have a ClassA which extends BaseGameActivity and then ClassB which extends ClassA and implements View.OnClickListener 
So I have all methods from https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init in class ClassB

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 127, accepted):

I had the same problem initially.  What I had to do was look at the full, unfiltered LogCat log.  There, I saw the message:

> GamesIntentService(17929): Using Google Play games services requires a metadata tag with the name "com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" in the application tag of your manifest

So, assuming you created an entry in your `strings.xml` called `app_id`, try adding the following to your `AndroidManifest.xml` under the `<application>` tag:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

You can find your APP_ID in the **Games Services** tab

[image: **Games Services** tab]

Comment: facepalm - I had it in `AndroidManifest.xml` but not on my `<application>` tag. thanks

Comment: Slight addition, do not replace ".APP_ID" with your APP ID from the developer console. I lost about 15 minutes with that :|

Comment: Another addition, do not put your app ID directly to the meta-data tag. It is resolved as integer when the system expects it to be a String :|

Comment: Another addition, by "unfiltered logs" it means checking the full device logs instead of your application-specific onces. Google Play Services is not part of your app so it's error messages aren't logged there.

Comment: Sorry, if this is a dumb question, but what to type as APP_ID there? I'm very new to Android developing.

Comment: One more thing, here is how to find your APP_ID :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363139/how-to-get-android-app-id-from-google-play-services

Answer (score 18):

Complementing *Hetabiquo* response, if you also use **Cloud Save** service in your game you also must to update your application's AndroidManifest.xml by adding the following meta-data tag inside `<application>` tag scope

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID" android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

Comment: helloe @Diego Palomar in my app i am already define app_id but it called about only numeric allowed but in my case app id creating using console.google.developer, like 123-30abcd.apps.googleusercontent.com ,so how can used my app id i face illegalstateException due to it,please give me solution

Comment: @NiravMehta: Use the number before the dash in that long string (Client Id) you see in Google Developers Console.

Comment: i try that also but that occure error  **"not yet connected"**

Comment: Try clearing the cache of google play services app on your device.

Comment: I'm still having the issues, added id, cleaned nothing works

Comment: I was veryyyyy confused by statement "under <application> tag"  he meant "inside <application> tag scope".

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same issue but had the meta-tag correct - I did look up the unfiltered logcat and found out, that it was searching for a different meta-tag.

The name of the meta-tag differs by the sort of Client Number you submitted in the GameHelper Constructor (if you use it).

```
new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES);
```

For me I accidentaly used CLIENT_ALL which leads to a wrong expectations of the meta-tag name. I changed it to CLIENT_GAMES and everything worked smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to *Hetabiquo*, you can fin your APP_ID in the **Games Services** tab :

[image: **Games Services** tab]

Answer (score 0):

I suffered from this bug for quite some time. I decided to go through the basegameutils package scanning each file one at a time. In gameHelperUtils class i found this method, getAppIdFromResource(). Inside it it requested app ID from resource. I remembered I had hardcoded the app ID in the manifest file. I then added a string resource of app_id in the strings file. To my amazement, the error was gone and the leaderboard showed up!