# how to get android app_id from google play services

Tags: android, google-play-services, keystroke, app-id

I created android application and hosted it on google play, but suddenly I deleted my project in Eclipse (from disk too) and now I am restoring some files from backup but I don't have old `app_id` in `res/values/strings.xml`

how can I get `app_id` from play services or .apk or keystore because I need it for `Google API integration`

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the redesigned google play console (2020), click the Play Games Services, then click setup and management, then click Configuration.
You will see information about your app, one field which is Authorization, and there you will find the application ID.

[image: Google play console side bar]

Comment: This is now the correct solution.

Answer (score 21):

Sign in to the google developers console here: https://play.google.com/apps/publish

You should be able to find it under your app.

EDIT: It's in the **Games Services** tab

[image]

Comment: @vmachacek Please see the pic I uploaded