# How to find Google Play app id?

Tags: android, google-play, app-id

How to find Google Play App Id (Numbers) by just knowing the package name or having a link to the app download page ?

example:

package name: `com.android.chrome`

What is the app ID and How to find it ?

This is the app id i want to get

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean app url?

Comment: no, not the app url. By having app url, I know the package name. Now, by knowing a package name, I need to know app ID (It should be a string or numbers)

Comment: Not getting your point. What is the use of that app ID? where will you find it?

Comment: Take a look here:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/images/consoleLocationOfApplicationId.png

By knowing app IDs, I can target those specific apps for advertising.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363139/how-to-get-android-app-id-from-google-play-services

Answer (score 7):

in the url, get the last word after "/". it is the application ID

Answer (score 2):

> How to find Google Play App Id (Numbers) by just knowing the package name or having a link to the app download page ?

You cannot. There's no reverse lookup feature offered by google, so if you have `40324351926` you cannot tell if this is valid id or just bunch of digits, nor you are able to tell if this is related to any android app and which one exactly.

Comment: He has a name of an app and wants to find a number (ID), not vice-versa.

Comment: You also cannot do that unless its your app.

Answer (score 0):

No need to worry, actually your **package name** is your **Google Play Store App ID.**
Package[image: Google Play Console] APP ID & PACKAGE NAME == com.abc.xyz

1. go to [enter link description here](https://play.google.com/console/developers)
2. here on the dashboard, you will see your package name under your app.

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't it be signing into your Google Play Developers account, clicking settings > developer account > account settings and copying the Developer account ID #? It's a bunch of numbers for me. I'm trying to figure this out, too. A developer group I'm joining is asking for the app package ID for resources & offerings

**[This link shows what I'm referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4kSW.png)**

Comment: Hello...
Inspect // Watch ...
Your answer is poorly elaborated.
It is useful to insert an effective response, with codes and references. Concluding a practical and efficient solution.
This platform is not just any forum. We are the largest help and support center for other programmers and developers in the world. Review the terms of the community and learn how to post;