# error during installation android app

Tags: android-studio

i have an application that collect the motiondata from (accelermeter and gyrscope sensors ) of the android phone and smartwatches at same time). i have problem , when i install the App on the phone i got this error

```
E/GMPM: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
 E/GMPM: Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.
 E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
```

the App is designed to collect only five min of the user's motion data and then stop automatically and send the data from the watch to the phone.then finally the phone send the data to my email. howover , the current problem the app doesnt stop in the watch and didnt send the data to the phone .
could i get anyhelp please ?
with my respect.

Comment: you should post gradle.build based on the error statement

Comment: Did you use the quickstart sample code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GoogleService failed to initialize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365369/googleservice-failed-to-initialize)

Comment: why didn't you choose a correct answer? still not working?

Answer (score 7):

I have same issue , just add this to string.xml

```
  <string name="google_app_id">your app id</string>
```

Comment: What is the app id ?

Comment: The applicationId configured on build.gradle ?
   defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.ofuscated.package'
        ...
    }

Comment: I dont understand you ? are you asking what app id mean or what

Comment: you can get google_app_id from google console where you create your app

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the configuration file generated by [this link](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cntapp=Default%20Demo%20App&cntpkg=com.google.samples.quickstart.signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fstart%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20with%20Try%20Sign-In)

And then as quoted in step 3:

> Copy the google-services.json file you just downloaded into the "app"
>   directory of your Android

Comment: i think this is the right answer, because it worked for me.

Comment: I have added the google-services.json file but still getting the same issue.

Comment: you can add a new line in strings.xml: `<string name="google_app_id">your app id</string>`

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363139/how-to-get-android-app-id-from-google-play-services