# Connecting to chromecast - a fatal developer error has occured

Tags: fatal-error, chromecast

> 06-22 08:17:30.568 31107-31119/? E/CastService: [instance-4]
>   ICastDeviceControllerListener can't be null. 06-22 08:17:30.578
>   8284-8601/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager: ContainerPolicy Service is
>   not yet ready!!! 06-22 08:17:30.578 31107-31136/? E/Publisher:
>   ProcessDatabaseInternal start 06-22 08:17:30.578 32326-32326/?
>   E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null 06-22 08:17:30.588
>   32326-32326/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                      java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>
> A fatal developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further
>   information.
>                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.jl$h.b(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.jl$h.g(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.jl$b.hy(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.jl$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
>                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 06-22 08:17:30.919
>   8284-8333/? E/android.os.Debug: !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o
>   /data/log/dumpstate_app_error 06-22 08:17:36.414 31107-31136/?
>   E/Publisher: ProcessDatabaseInternal start

I have this issue while connecting to chromecast. I've gone back to the previous code, and I still have the same issue, so something must have changed with chromecast. When I click my chromecast device to connect to "Sankey", this is when the crash occurs. Image below:
[image: crash occurs when "Sankey" is clicked]

Research on this has pointed to a problem with the manifest, and not declaring the app_id properly. Below is my manifest file which shows this, and also the google play services version.

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/control_panel_app_id" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Here is the declarations in strings.xml with last 4 digits blocked out:

string name="control_panel_app_id" translatable="false">75468636XXXX

Checking the logs in vicinity of the crash has not given me any useful information.

Answer (score 1):

My app was previously running cast SDK v1. I had two options to fix it:  1) wait approximately 3 months until google updated their gms code. 2) upgrade to cast v2.

I chose option 2.

Upgrading to cast v2 was done by the following:

1. change gradle files, so everything referencing any part of google play is version 11.0.0.  ex: com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:11.0.0
2. required deleting references to "AppStateManager" in GameHelper.java (this is not necessary for cast, but was part of my project).
3. required changing minSdkVersion from 11 to 14 :(
4. in gradle file(s), update compileSdkVersion to 25, and buildToolsVersion to 25.0.2

Hope this helps someone out.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16599446/5832311). Make sure that you have it inside `<application>` tag. Also make sure that you are using the correct App ID. Here's [how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363139/how-to-get-android-app-id-from-google-play-services). Hope this helps!

Comment: This is not the issue. All of this was working previously, but is due to a change in chromecast.

Comment: It looks like the problem is I need to migrate android sender app from Cast SDK v2 to v3.    There is a document here:   https://developers.google.com/cast/v2/android_migrate_sender     I have started the process, but it is not working yet. If I'm able to get it working, I'll post the accepted answer in more detail.

Comment: A document from google says that SDK v2 should still be working, so the above is not the issue. Still looking for a solution to this problem.