# Missing metadata tag with the name "com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID" in the application tag of your manifest

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-signin

---

NUM_OF_TRIES_TO_FIX_THIS=12;//I'm counting the apk's

So we are having a big problem, we are 2 steps away from releasing our app, but we are not able to implement google play services into our app.
It keeps telling us this in the log:

```
03-29 22:36:21.709: E/ValidateServiceOp(9477): Using Google Play games services requires a     metadata tag with the name "com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" in the application tag of your manifest
03-29 22:36:21.729: E/ValidateServiceOp(9477): Missing metadata tag with the name "com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID" in the application tag of your manifest.
03-29 22:36:21.809: E/ValidateServiceOp(9477): Using Google Play games services requires a metadata tag with the name "com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" in the application tag of your manifest
03-29 22:36:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(13931): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-29 22:36:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(13931): java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information.
03-29 22:36:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(13931):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.eh$h.b(Unknown Source)
03-29 22:36:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(13931):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.eh$h.a(Unknown Source)
03-29 22:36:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(13931):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.eh$b.ec(Unknown Source)
03-29 22:36:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(13931):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.eh$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
03-29 22:36:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(13931):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-29 22:36:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(13931):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-29 22:36:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(13931):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
03-29 22:36:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(13931):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-29 22:36:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(13931):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-29 22:36:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(13931):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
03-29 22:36:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(13931):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
03-29 22:36:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(13931):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

But we have the id in our manifest!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.uraniumdevelopers.etchcubes"
    android:versionCode="6"
    android:versionName="0.4" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID"
            android:value="457870338644" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="457870338644" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.uraniumdevelopers.etchcubes.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And the initialization of the services goes like this:

```
    GoogleApiClient.Builder builder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(
            getBaseContext());
    builder.addApi(Games.API).addApi(Plus.API).addApi(AppStateManager.API)
            .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .addScope(AppStateManager.SCOPE_APP_STATE).setViewForPopups(rl);
    mClient = builder.build();
```

We would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add your app_id in strings.xml and mention that id in manifest file.

For more info check this answer. Importantly the comments in the answer. [Fatal exception in playservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595225/initializing-games-client-in-android)

Answer (score 4):

replace  4 -> \u0034
for example

`<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
    android:value="\u003457870338644" />`

visit
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/meta-data-element.html