# Android - Google Play Service, Game Client, Run time Error

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have checked a few different questions already like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595225/initializing-games-client-in-android/)

I am trying to implement a Google sign in and have been referring to https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin/ but cannot figure out how to resolve this error

I currently have the following meta data in my Manifest file

```
      <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
               android:value="@string/app_id" />
      <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

My LogCat error looks like:

```
- 04-01 15:25:28.461: E/AndroidRuntime(30017): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
- 04-01 15:25:28.461: E/AndroidRuntime(30017): java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal   developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information.
- 04-01 15:25:28.461: E/AndroidRuntime(30017):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.eh$h.b(Unknown Source)
- 04-01 15:25:28.461: E/AndroidRuntime(30017):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.eh$h.a(Unknown Source)
- 04-01 15:25:28.461: E/AndroidRuntime(30017):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.eh$b.ec(Unknown Source)
- 04-01 15:25:28.461: E/AndroidRuntime(30017):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.eh$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
- 04-01 15:25:28.461: E/AndroidRuntime(30017):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
- 04-01 15:25:28.461: E/AndroidRuntime(30017):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
- 04-01 15:25:28.461: E/AndroidRuntime(30017):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
- 04-01 15:25:28.461: E/AndroidRuntime(30017):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
- 04-01 15:25:28.461: E/AndroidRuntime(30017):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
- 04-01 15:25:28.461: E/AndroidRuntime(30017):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
- 04-01 15:25:28.461: E/AndroidRuntime(30017):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
- 04-01 15:25:28.461: E/AndroidRuntime(30017):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am also getting a warning earlier:

```
- 04-01 15:45:45.408: W/PopupManager(1075): You have not specified a View to use as content view for popups. Falling back to the Activity content view which may not work properly in future versions of the API. Use setViewForPopups() to set your content view.
```

I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it I've tried overriding and calling in the onCreate()

```
setViewForPopups()
```

but eclipse does not show this method exists.

My current MainActivity looks like

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseGameActivity implements OnClickListener {

boolean mExplicitSignOut = false;
boolean mInSignInFlow = false;

GoogleApiClient mClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GameView gameView = (GameView) findViewById(R.id.game);

    GoogleApiClient.Builder builder = 
            new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this);
        builder.addApi(Games.API)
               .addApi(Plus.API)
               .addApi(AppStateManager.API)
               .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
               .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
               .addScope(AppStateManager.SCOPE_APP_STATE);
        mClient = builder.build();

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (!mInSignInFlow && !mExplicitSignOut) {
        // auto sign in
        mClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onSignInFailed() {
    // TODO SignInFailed
    Toast.makeText(this, "Sign in Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onSignInSucceeded() {
    // TODO SignInSucceeded
    Toast.makeText(this, "Sign in Succeeded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO onClick
    Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
}
```

Comment: have you managed to solve that? I have the same problem

Comment: Not completely sure but I believe it's because I haven't made a certified Google developer account yet. They give you certain codes to access their databases.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have all 3 meta-data tags in your manifest file -

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you haven't configured OAuth2 client id in [Google Deveopers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project).