# Google Play Services Error - Bug report Incomprehensible

Tags: java, android, libgdx, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have released an alpha version of my app with Google Play services.
However, I have encountered this error when I tested the app on a phone with Google Play services. 
I hadn't got this error during compilation or running the app on a phone with an out of date Google Play Service. 
I Googled this error and in stack overflow but it didn't give me much answer.
If anyone have any idea, please help.

By the way, I didn't enable pro-guard, so that isn't a problem

Here is the bug report:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred.
Check the logs for further information.
at com.google.android.gms.internal.jl$h.b(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.jl$h.g(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.jl$b.hy(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.jl$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5338)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

By the way, I use LibGdx, and I used google play services for leader boards, a achievements.
I have followed [this](http://theinvader360.blogspot.ca/2013/10/google-play-game-services-tutorial-example.html) tutorial but it didn't help me much.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your app seems to be obfuscated by ProGuard. Take a look at http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#decoding to learn how to decode the bug report

Comment: It is possible the ProGuard is the source of your problems. I have, on several occasions, tried running an obfuscated form of my project that was created with ProGuard, only to find that it does not work unless it is ini its deobfuscated form.

Comment: Have you got the proguard settings detailed here: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Proguard Also show the code that causes this exception.

Comment: Sorry Guys but I didn't Use proguard

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595225/initializing-games-client-in-android. <<-- Maybe it was a meta? Since no one has linked to this yet.

Comment: It's the google play services classes that are obfuscated by proguard. There's no trace of the developer's app package (unless they'e removed it). Does this mean that this is a bug in the play services framework?

Comment: Can you check whether your manifest has your play games`APP_ID`? Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16599446/1773325

Comment: @iceman, your suggestion was very close to what I did wrong. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to post the answer after I solved the problem several months ago!

The problem was an extra space in the ID of the leaderboard.

Supposed that my leaderboard ID is "as129sadf92349dsfaj".

I wrote "as129sadf92349dsfaj  ".

So google play services gave me this error.