# Android Google play service, A fatal developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information

Tags: android, google-play-services

I was using google play service in my game [MathBuzz](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mass.mathbuzz) Now Google play service library has changed and, I am following this [GIT HUB SOURCE](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples)

I was able so compile but I am getting crash saying

```
E/AndroidRuntime(20184): Process: com.mass.mathbuzz, PID: 20184
E/AndroidRuntime(20184): java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information.
E/AndroidRuntime(20184):    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(20184):    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi$zza.zzr(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(20184):    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi$zzc.zznQ(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(20184):    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(20184):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(20184):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(20184):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5329)
E/AndroidRuntime(20184):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(20184):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime(20184):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
E/AndroidRuntime(20184):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

my `AndroidManifest` is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mass.mathbuzz">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mass.applist.AppListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initializing Games Client in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595225/initializing-games-client-in-android)