# Google Play Game Services showAchievments()

Tags: java, android, google-play-games

I'm trying to show achievements on my Android app. I'm using method for this provided by https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/achievements

```
private void showAchievements() {
    System.out.println("start showAchievements");
    Games.getAchievementsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
        .getAchievementsIntent()
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Intent>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Intent intent) {
                System.out.println("in onSuccess");
                startActivityForResult(intent, RC_ACHIEVEMENT_UI);
            }
        });
```

but when I'm calling the method I'm getting the EXCEPTION:

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GoogleApiHandler
                                                                                   Process: com.my.application PID: 1927
                                                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Games APIs requires https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games_lite function.

I'm thinking that problem form **Games.getAchievementsClient()** method, but can't fix

Comment: Did you go through the document for troubleshooting issues provided by Google? https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting

Comment: I just did it. Everything is correct. It doesn't help.

Comment: I stumbled over these two answers, maybe they could fix your problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16599446/2734302
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36414508/2734302

Comment: Thanks, but no, my problem is different. My AndroidManifest.xml is currect

Comment: Hi! I've got your same error with both `getAchievements` and `getPlayersClient`. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Oiproks I just used the sample from Google and it works.
https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart#step_3_modify_your_code

Comment: Seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47594187/google-play-games

Answer (score 1):

It seems your GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this) has no Games.SCOPE_GAMES_LITE.

You can check it by GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions. If there is no such permission you should request it with GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions or receive new account with GoogleSignInClient.silentSignIn.