# Google Play Services: Account has no SCOPE_GAME_LITE permissions and cannot view Leaderboard

Tags: android, google-play-games

I followed the instructions on https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/signin and can successfully sign in and get data from an account (like .getEmail(), etc).

But when i try to show the leaderboard, i get the error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Games APIs requires https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games_lite function.

```
Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
            .getLeaderboardIntent(getString(R.string.leaderboard_highscores))
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Intent>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Intent intent) {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_LEADERBOARD_UI);
                }
            });
```

Indeed,

```
GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(account, Games.SCOPE_GAMES_LITE));
```

returns false.

Everything in the Google Play Console should be set up correctly.
I also tried silentSignIn() without success.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: short update: I was creating the googleSignInClient with options "DEFAULT_SIGN_IN". When switching to "DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN" i cannot log in anymore.
But when compiling first with DEFAULT_SIGN_IN and then using SilentSignIn with "DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN" the SCOPE_GAMES_LITE permission is granted. Still cannot show the leaderboards though...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Play Games](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47594187/google-play-games)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so i solved the issue...
Turns out i only had to wait for ~36h for all the changes to take effect.

This was even though the game console told me that everything was published and ready to use.

So don't get crazy and just wait.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Troubleshooting Issues in Your Android Game : Anonymous listeners](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting#anonymous_listeners)

> Do not use anonymous listeners. Anonymous listeners are unreliable
>   because the Play Games SDK maintains them as weak references, which
>   means that they might be reclaimed by the garbage collector before
>   they are invoked. Instead, you should implement the listener using a
>   persistent object such as the Activity.