# Google Games APIs requires games_lite function

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I work with Google Play Games Services. I took the code from the official example. Try with API 27 and with API 17.

All works only under one account (owner Google Developer Console), under any other - no.

I get this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GoogleApiHandler
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Games APIs requires https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games_lite function.
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.GamesClientImpl.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzab.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzab.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.GamesClientImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.games.Games$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbo.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbm.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbm.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

I checked everything and as [described here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting).

My gradle:

```
def gmsVersion = '12.0.1'
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:$gmsVersion"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$gmsVersion"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:$gmsVersion"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:$gmsVersion"
```

and

```
isGooglePlayServicesAvailable = SUCCESS
```

I spent a very long time looking for a solution, but I did not find it.

Comment: Did you include the Games.SCOPE_GAMES_LITE scope as mentioned in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47594187/google-play-games)?

Comment: Ooops, I was inattentive. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

True path is **requestScopes(Games.SCOPE_GAMES_LITE)**:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions
    .Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestScopes(Games.SCOPE_GAMES_LITE)
    .requestEmail()
    .build();
```

Comment: I have got an exception com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12501. Should I set .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id)) also?

Comment: requestEmail isn't really necessary

Comment: anivaler: With APIExcepton you can get error(status) code: ex.getStatusCode(). This is one of the CommonStatusCodes constants that may tell you what is going on. Also getMessage() may be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Following this Google Game Doc should be enough: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/signin

You should use:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions
   .Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
   .requestEmail()
   .build();
```

Comment: Hi @geisterfurz007, thanks for your feedback. I added some context to the answer. No need to mark it as invalid since this can confuse people.

Comment: Comment removed and flag retracted. Thanks for updating the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

In my case, it happened when I added a new developer in my google console.
When some changes are made in the console, even though google gives us a green flag instantly, it is taking some time to get activated. My problem got solved without me doing anything but to wait a couple of hrs.

> Note that as per [Developer's Blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/games-authentication-adopting-google.html),
>
> ```
> GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(
>                GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN).build();
> ```
>
> is sufficient for `Games Lite scope`.

**Note: This is as per 14th November 2018**