# Can't sign in with Google Play Game Services

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-signin, google-play-games

Trying to log in to firebase with google and use google play game services, and am getting the following exception when i try to login:

```
W/MainActivity: Google sign in failed
    com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 13: 
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(Unknown Source:14)
        at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(Unknown Source:47)
        at ca.doophie.scarletflames.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.kt:63)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7276)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4264)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4312)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1644)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I followed the guide [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin?utm_source=studio) to set up google sign in only changing my Sign in options (see below). I also turned on google play services for the app in the google play console, added both android debug keystore SHA1 and release SHA1 key.

Here's the code:

```
// Configure Google Sign In
val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
        .requestIdToken(context.getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
        .requestEmail()
        .build()
```

and in my manifest i have this:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
    android:value="@string/app_id" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.API_KEY"
    android:value=  "@string/api_key" />
```

and these are in my gradle:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:15.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
```

and finally this is where i do the sign in:

```
val signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient?.signInIntent ?: return
startActivityForResult(signInIntent, rc)
```

and:

```
public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == LoginController.RC_SIGN_IN) {
        val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
        try {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
            loginController?.firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account)
        } catch (e: ApiException) {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e) //Exception is here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> ` ...the title is somewhat misleading, because it is an **un-handled exception** in `line 13` and not an API exception with `error code 13`.

Comment: Actually i just noticed that wasnt the issue - i had just changed my DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN to DEFAULT_SIGN_IN and thats why it worked, then i started getting the issue posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49656327/google-games-apis-requires-games-lite-function) and when i switch it back to games sign in i get the exception i posted here

Comment: you obviously need to use `GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN`, while you might not be requesting the proper scopes, alike `Games.SCOPE_GAMES` or `Games.SCOPE_GAMES_LITE`

Comment: there's also lots of fields & methods marked as deprecated ...
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/Games