# Google Api Client causes crash with unknown error

Tags: android, google-signin, google-play-games

I've got a sample app from a website to learn about Google Games Signin.  The App crashes on start.  Here's the [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/get-started-with-google-play-games-services--cms-27755) to the website I'm using.  Here is the `Java` class of the only Activity.  It is supposed to prompt a signin when the application is opened.

```
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
import com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
    private Button mainButton;
    private TextView scoreView;
    private TextView timeView;

    private int score = 0;
    private boolean playing = false;

    GoogleApiClient apiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    mainButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.main_button);
    scoreView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score_view);
    timeView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.time_view);




    apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Games.API)
            .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not Sign in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .build();



    mainButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!playing) {
                // The first click
                playing = true;
                mainButton.setText("Keep Clicking");

                // Initialize CountDownTimer to 60 seconds
                new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        timeView.setText("Time remaining: " + millisUntilFinished/1000);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        playing = false;
                        timeView.setText("Game over");
                        mainButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }.start();  // Start the timer
            } else {
                // Subsequent clicks
                score++;
                scoreView.setText("Score: " + score + " points");
            }
        }
    });
  }

}
```

And here's the logs:

```
07-01 11:20:48.616 31570-31570/carsquared.mylittlegame E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: carsquared.mylittlegame, PID: 31570
                                                                     Theme: themes:{com.teslacoilsw.launcher=overlay:system, com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher=overlay:org.cyanogenmod.hexolibre, default=overlay:org.cyanogenmod.hexolibre, iconPack:system, fontPkg:system, com.android.systemui=overlay:org.cyanogenmod.hexolibre, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:system}
                                                                     java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information.
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zza.zzu(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zze.zzxa(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf$zzd.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                         at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595225/initializing-games-client-in-android). In `AndroidManifest.xml` under the `<application> tag`, add  `meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"`.

If you also use [**Cloud Save**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17787797/5832311) service in your game you also must to update your application's AndroidManifest.xml by adding the following meta-data tag inside `<application>` tag scope. `meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID"`

Answer (score 0):

Ensure all google play service dependencies are of same version that was the fix for me